# Why am I getting black screen for this code?

Tags: texmaker

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}




\begin{document}
\begin{TeXtoEPS}
\begin{pspicture}
\scalebox{1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1.5507812)(6.1871877,1.5307813)
\pspolygon[linewidth=0.04](0.701875,1.5107813)(0.701875,-0.94921875)
(5.481875,-0.96921873)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(0.25546876,0.22578125){$b$}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(2.5754688,-1.3742187){$c$}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(4.3554688,0.8857812){$a=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$}
\end{pspicture}
}


\end{pspicture}
\end{TeXtoEPS}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. I don't know about pstricks, but I notice that commenting on the `TeXtoEPS` environment, there's no problem. Pstrick specialists can explain what's going on.

Comment: I remember that pstricks requires the compilation string `LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf` and does not compile with `pdfLaTeX`.

Comment: Or, simpler, you can compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: Do you really need to obtain en .eps file?

Comment: hello, for now, I can remove eps package. now it shows the diagram. but actually I want to run in command prompt:

"dvips -E -q -o myfigure.eps myfigure.dvi"

Answer (score 1):

I can compile your code but you should not put a `{pspicture}` in another `{pspicture}` as you do. You should use `\psset{unit=7mm}` (or other) to change the scale of the picture.

With `latex myfigure.tex` and `dvips -E -q -o myfigure.eps myfigure.dvi` I obtain a correct EPS file with the correct bouding box...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
% \usepackage{pst-solides3d}


\begin{document}
\begin{TeXtoEPS}
\psset{unit=7mm}%
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1.5507812)(6.1871877,1.5307813)
\pspolygon[linewidth=0.04](0.701875,1.5107813)(0.701875,-0.94921875)
(5.481875,-0.96921873)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(0.25546876,0.22578125){$b$}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(2.5754688,-1.3742187){$c$}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(4.3554688,0.8857812){$a=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{TeXtoEPS}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]